Needing reference on fundamental set of solution for differential equation on vector fields
Let $L$ be a differential operator on functions $f:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
Under some assumptions, we can find the solutions of $Lf = g$ where $f$ and $g$ are both functions from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}$, by finding the solutions $K$ of $LK = \delta$. Then $K:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $f=K*g$.
$K$ is called the Green's function of $L$.
But if $f:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}^N$, I found in research papers (such as this one) that $K$ may exist also but it is now $K:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^N$ and the definition of the product of convolution seems different:
$f=K*g$ with $f_i(x)=\sum_j{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}{K_{ij}(x-y)g_j(y)dy}}$
This as been discussed also in this post which mentions Oseen's tensor instead of Green's function but it is discussed in a particular case.
I'd appreciate a reference on the determination of a set of solution for vector-valued function which will clearly state the correct convolution formula and how is modified the $LK=\delta$ equation for $K:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^N$.

All differential operators $L$ on vector fields act via $(Lf)_i = \sum_{j} L_{ij} f_j$ for some scalar operators $L_{ij}$ (this is the case for curl and divergence for instance).
To derive an appropriate version of $LK=\delta$ for matrix-valued $L$, assume $K$ is matrix valued and the formula for $f$ takes the form $f_i = \sum_j K_{ij}*g_j$. Then $(Lf)_i = \sum_{j,k} L_{ij}K_{jk}*g_k$. In order for this to equal $g_i$ we need $\sum_j L_{ij}K_{jk} = \delta_{ik} \delta$, where $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kronecker delta, or in other words, $LK = I\delta$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
